# I am getting two sub_id for the same order_id. I want one sub_id for one order_id

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table: lu_rd

```
sub_id  CUST_ORDER_ID   loc_id  active_flag
156386  7731100 105 Y
156387  7731101 105 Y
1360780 1360780 101 Y
1360781 1360781 101 Y
```

Table: order_rel

```
PARENTORDER_ID  CHILDORDER_ID
7731100 8081859
7731101 8081859
1360780 7110643
1360781 7110643
```

Table: Header_table

```
header_key  ORDER_ID
2782    7110643
2584    8081859
```

Table: Line_table

```
ORDER_ID    Lin_key header_key
7110643 2799    2782
7110643 2793    2782
8081859 2585    2584
8081859 2586    2584
```

--Query Used:

```
select H.header_key,
    L.Lin_key,
    a.SUB_ID,
    a.ORDER_ID as order_id 
    from
    ((
        --
        ((
        SELECT
            S.SUB_ID,
            WO.CHILDORDER_ID AS ORDER_ID
        FROM
            ( db.schema.lu_rd S JOIN db.schema.order_rel  WO ON ((WO.PARENTORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50) = 
(S.CUST_ORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50)))))
        WHERE
            (S.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'))  
    UNION ALL (
    SELECT
        S.SUB_ID,
        WO.PARENTORDER_ID AS ORDER_ID
    FROM
        ( WHPRD_INT.DWADMIN.lu_rd S JOIN db.schema.order_rel WO ON ((WO.CHILDORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50) = 
(S.CUST_ORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50)))))
    WHERE
        (S.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'))) A
    --  
    JOIN db.schema.Header_table H ON
        ((((A.ORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50)))= H.ORDER_ID::VARCHAR(50))))
    JOIN db.schema.Line_table L ON
        ((L.HEADER_KEY = H.HEADER_KEY)))
```

--Since there are 2-PARENTORDER_ID for the CHILDORDER_ID, is causing the problem. Any suggestions as how to get only one sub_id for one order_id? The query before the first join is creating 2-sub_id for one order_id.

Comment: The query that i have used is a query which is getting used to create a table and that table should have one sub_id for an order id. But because of this query, the table is having 2-sub_id since data in table: order_rel, is causing the issue.

Comment: Can you share the desired output?

Comment: Is the SQL targeting `mysql` or `snowflake` or both? as you seems to have over tagged the question.

Comment: Yes siemeon, i over tagged it since i wanted some body to help me and sql would be same in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with example data given by:

```
WITH lu_rd AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (156386,  7731100, 105, 'Y'),
        (156387,  7731101, 105, 'Y'),
        (1360780, 1360780, 101, 'Y'),
        (1360781, 1360781, 101, 'Y')
        v(sub_id,  cust_order_id,   loc_id, active_flag)
), order_rel AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        (7731100, 8081859),
        (7731101, 8081859),
        (1360780, 7110643),
        (1360781, 7110643)
        v(parentorder_id,  childorder_id)
), header_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (2782, 7110643),
        (2584, 8081859)
        v(header_key, order_id)
), line_table AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (7110643, 2799, 2782),
        (7110643, 2793, 2782),
        (8081859, 2585, 2584),
        (8081859, 2586, 2584)
        v(order_id, lin_key, header_key)
),
```

and re-writing the SQL to also use CTE to remove some of the bracketing..

```
child_orders AS (
    SELECT
        s.sub_id,
        wo.childorder_id AS order_id
    FROM lu_rd AS s 
    JOIN order_rel wo 
        ON wo.parentorder_id = s.cust_order_id
    WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y'
), parent_orders AS (
    SELECT
        s.sub_id,
        wo.parentorder_id AS order_id
    FROM lu_rd AS s 
    JOIN order_rel AS wo 
        ON wo.childorder_id = s.cust_order_id
    WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y'
), the_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM child_orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM parent_orders
)
SELECT h.header_key,
    l.lin_key,
    a.sub_id,
    a.order_id AS order_id 
FROM the_union AS a
JOIN header_table AS h
    ON a.order_id = h.order_id
JOIN line_table AS l 
    ON l.header_key = h.header_key
```

you do get some double ups:

```
HEADER_KEY   LIN_KEY    SUB_ID    ORDER_ID
2584         2585       156386    8081859
2584         2586       156386    8081859
2584         2585       156387    8081859
2584         2586       156387    8081859
2782         2799       1360780   7110643
2782         2793       1360780   7110643
2782         2799       1360781   7110643
2782         2793       1360781   7110643
```

so stripping it back a bit:

```
<include data with>
child_orders AS (
    SELECT
        s.sub_id,
        wo.childorder_id AS order_id
    FROM lu_rd AS s 
    JOIN order_rel wo 
        ON wo.parentorder_id = s.cust_order_id
    WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y'
), parent_orders AS (
    SELECT
        s.sub_id,
        wo.parentorder_id AS order_id
    FROM lu_rd AS s 
    JOIN order_rel AS wo 
        ON wo.childorder_id = s.cust_order_id
    WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y'
)
    SELECT *, 'c' as t FROM child_orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'p' as t FROM parent_orders
;
```

which gives you for this data:

```
SUB_ID  ORDER_ID    T
156386  8081859 c
156387  8081859 c
1360780 7110643 c
1360781 7110643 c
```

which is not too surprising as your that is your data.

So depending on the needs of your business you need to decide how you discard a sub_id to get only a single ORDER_ID

one method is to take the first (lowest sub_id) and the simplest place you put that is in the the_union area as such.

```
), the_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT *, 'c' as t FROM child_orders
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *, 'p' as t FROM parent_orders
    )
    QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by order_id order by sub_id) = 1
)
```

which gives:

```
SUB_ID  ORDER_ID    T
1360780 7110643 c
156386  8081859 c
```

how ever when we put that back into your full SQL we get:

```
HEADER_KEY  LIN_KEY SUB_ID  ORDER_ID
2782        2799    1360780 7110643
2782        2793    1360780 7110643
2584        2585    156386  8081859
2584        2586    156386  8081859
```

because you `line_table` also has duplicates on both `order_id` and `header_key`, so I will assume that is intended.